# Rails: How to define a function in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

In my task file `post.rake`, I want to reuse a function

```
  def save_post(title, href, source)
    post = Post.new(title: title, url: href, source: source)
    if post.save
      puts title + 'saved'
    else
      puts title + 'not saved'
    end
  end
```

However, when I define it in this file and re-use it, it returns

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `save_post' for main:Object
```

The `post.rake` looks like this:

```
task :fetch_post => :environment do
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

  url = 'http://example.com'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url) )
  puts doc.css("title").text
  doc.css(".a").each do |item_info|
    title = item_info.text
    href = item_info['href']
    save_post(title, href)
  end

  def save_post(title, href)
    post = Post.new(title: title, url: href)
    if post.save
      puts title + 'saved'
    else
      puts title + 'not saved'
    end
  end
end
```

The content-scraping part works. I just move the post-saving code out, wanting to abstract the method out.

Where should I put the `def method`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OOOH~~~,function postion is wrong, like this, it works:

```
task :fetch_post => :environment do
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

  def save_post(title, href)
    post = Post.new(title: title, url: href)
    if post.save
      puts title + 'saved'
    else
      puts title + 'not saved'
    end
  end

  url = 'http://example.com'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url) )
  puts doc.css("title").text
  doc.css(".a").each do |item_info|
    title = item_info.text
    href = item_info['href']
    save_post(title, href)
  end
end
```

Comment: this method available only in this task.

Comment: @Зелёный: maybe that's the desired effect.

Comment: Yes, this is better. And I'm sorry I didn't say this before. Because I repeat capture other url in this task as well. That's how this method get reused

Comment: I just want a handy abstraction. Not something too strickly object oriented programming.

Answer (score 8):

If you define methods in a rake task, they become accessible globally, which may have undesired side-effects. A cleaner approach is to use an inline lambda (or move the method to some class in the app)

```
task :fetch_post => :environment do
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

  save_post = ->(title, href) {
    post = Post.new(title: title, url: href)
    if post.save
      puts title + 'saved'
    else
      puts title + 'not saved'
    end
  }

  url = 'http://example.com'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url) )
  puts doc.css("title").text
  doc.css(".a").each do |item_info|
    title = item_info.text
    href = item_info['href']
    save_post.call(title, href)
  end

end
```

Comment: oy i been wrong, this proc avaliable outside of this task

Comment: @Зелёный: huh? What you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's intended.

Answer (score 1):

You should define method before and outside of task:

```
task :fetch_post => :environment do
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

  url = 'http://example.com'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url) )
  puts doc.css("title").text
  doc.css(".a").each do |item_info|
    title = item_info.text
    href = item_info['href']
    save_post(title, href)
  end
end

def save_post(title, href)
  post = Post.new(title: title, url: href)
  if post.save
    puts title + 'saved'
  else
    puts title + 'not saved'
  end
end
```

But i think this logic should be in model.

`#app/models/post.rb`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.save_post(title, href)
    post = Post.new(title: title, url: href)
    if post.save
      puts title + 'saved'
    else
      puts title + 'not saved'
    end
   end
 end
```

Comment: I think that puts the function in the global namespace

Comment: yes this puts the method in the global namespace which can be dangerous.